passing parameter to Function inside of swal after $.ajax call
I am new to Javascript and jQuery.   I am running into an issue passing data to my function, ProcessFileFromGrid() in the onClick event in JS.  It all tests out fine, but then I wanted to do something with the result sent back from the Ajax call.
In this example I call API /uploadPhysical and then I check for sucess: or error:.   That all works great.
In the Success: callback, I display a question to the user, "Upload Complete!  Do you want to process your files?".   If they say yes, I do a series of things in the onClick event. One of the things that I do is pass "data" to the ProcessFilesFromGrid() function.   It works fine without the data being passed, so I know its how I am passing "data".  data comes back from the call.  I have tried different things, but I get a JS errors in F12 console.  I also tried: ProcessFileFromGrid('" + data + "'\
How would I do this?
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    mimetype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: commonUrl + "api/FileTransfer/UploadPhysical",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
    },
    //dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    async: true,
    // cache: false,
    // timeout: 600000,
    success: function (data) {
         
         var screenExitMessage = "Upload Completed!<br/><br/>Do you want to process your files ?";
        alert(data);
         swal.fire({
            html:
                "<button type='button' role='button' tabindex='0' class='btn swal2-styled btn-outline btn-outline-success' onclick='swal.close(); ProcessFilesFromGrid(data);'><i class='fa-solid fa-check fs-1'></i>Yes</button>" +
                "<button type='button' role='button' tabindex='0' class='btn swal2-styled btn-light-primary' onclick='swal.close(); ReloadFileGrids();'>No</button>",
            title: screenExitMessage,
            text: screenExitMessage,
            icon: 'question',
            showCancelButton: false,
            showConfirmButton: false,
        }).then(function () {
                
            // swal.close();
              // ReloadFileGrids();
        });
    },
    error: function (e) {
       
        swal.fire({
            text: e.responseText,
            icon: "error",
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonText: "OK",
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: "btn font-weight-bold btn-light-primary"
            }
        })
    }
});
}
else {
    swal.fire({
    text: "Please select a file to upload",
    icon: "error",
    buttonsStyling: false,
    confirmButtonText: "OK",
    customClass: {
        confirmButton: "btn font-weight-bold btn-light-primary"
        }
    })
}

function ProcessFilesFromGrid(databaseName) {
enableControls(false, false);
var username = localStorage.getItem("Username");
var orgId = $("#ddlBorrowerName").val();
var processOption = $("#ddlProcessOption").val();
var databaseOption = $("#ddlDatabaseOption").val();
if (databaseName) {
    databaseOption = databaseName;
}

console.log("Process Option: " + processOption);
console.log("Database Option: " + databaseOption);

var apigetlink = "/Upload/ProcessFiles?Username=" + username + "&OrgId=" + orgId + "&ProcessOption=" + processOption + "&DatabaseOption=" + databaseOption;

AjaxPostBackendAsyncCallback(apigetlink, model, function (data) {
    if (data && data.status == 1) {
        swal.fire({
            html: data.message,
            icon: "success",
            icon: "success",
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonText: "OK",
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: "btn font-weight-bold btn-light-primary"
            }
        });
        ReloadFileGrids();
    }
    else {
        var message = data.message;
        message = "Processing Issues!<br /><br />";
        message += data.message.replaceAll("<br />","<br /><br />");
        swal.fire({
            html: message,
            icon: "info",
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonText: "OK",
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: "btn font-weight-bold btn-light-primary"
            }
        });
        ReloadFileGrids();
    }

}, errorCallback);

}


To be clear, you want the data you already entered in a form? If so, post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>).  Include HTML since you have jQuery as well.

I am trying to pass the contents of data to my JS function and I think my issue is that I have to make sure I adhere to HTML when I concatenate the contents of data.
Someone noted that I had to make sure I use &quote; because it is HTML.   I am going to try that and get back to this feed.

ok, that worked.   Sorry for the big writeup when in the end it was not using the correct quotes around the value.
